# My problem is Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm

Tags: django, forms, hash, passwords

I try to do sign up and login form using Modelform. I have form to sign up user but it can't set password becouse in admin panel in user lap in password field I have "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm." Can anyone help me?
My form succesful submit form. Please help me solve this problem.

view

```
def sign_up(request):
context ={}
who ={"teacher": Teacher, "student": Student}
form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid() and request.POST.get("who"):
        user = form.save()
        person = who[request.POST.get("who")]
        person(user=user).save()
        return render(request, 'school/index.html')
context['form'] = form
return render(request, 'registration/sign_up.html', context)
```

form

```
class UserSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserSignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['first_name'].required = True
    self.fields['last_name'].required = True

who = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=[('student', 'Student'), ('teacher', 'Teacher')],
    label="",
    required=True,
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(
        attrs={'style':'max-width: 20em; ', 'autocomplete':'off', })
)
password = forms.CharField(
    label="Password",
    validators=[MinLengthValidator(8, message="Minimum 8 characters")],
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
confirm_password = forms.CharField(
    label="Confirm password",
    validators=[MinLengthValidator(8, message="Minimum 8 characters"), ],
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('who', "username", 'first_name', 'last_name', "password", )
    help_texts = {"username": None}
    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={}),
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={}),

    }

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserSignUpForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
    if password != confirm_password:
        msg = _(f'Password and confirm password does not match')
        self.add_error('password', msg)
        self.add_error('confirm_password', msg)


helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_tag = 'false'
helper.attrs = {"novalidate": True, 'autocomplete':'off'}
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
helper.field_class = 'col-md-8 '
helper.label_class = 'col-md-4'
helper.layout = Layout(
    Row(
        Column(
            Field('who', css_class='form-group', style='margin-left:200px'),
            Field('username', css_class='form-group ', style=''),
            Field('first_name', css_class='form-group'),
            Field('last_name', css_class='form-group'),
            Field('password', css_class='form-group'),
            Field('confirm_password', css_class='form-group'),

            FormActions(
                Submit('save', 'Sign up', css_class="btn-primary"),
                Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'),
                ),

        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sign up view, you should include the validation of the password.
First, create an instance of the user:

```
person = form.save(commit=False)
```

then add the password with a line like:

```
person.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
```

Just before implementing
`person.save()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's work now int that like below. Thanks!

```
def sign_up(request):
context ={}
who ={"teacher": Teacher, "student": Student}
form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST or None)
context['form'] = form
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid() and request.POST.get("who"):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save()
        person = who[request.POST.get("who")]
        person(user=user).save()
        return render(request, 'school/index.html', context)
```